# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS -- Printing Service Not Available

Tags: 18.04, printing, services

My printer no longer shows up in my Settings -> Devices GUI menu.  Instead it says "Sorry! The system printing service doesn't seem to be available."

I tried searching the 'net for ideas and I ran these terminal commands with the following output:

```
john@john-max:~$ sudo service cups restart
john@john-max:~$ systemctl status cups

● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Mon 2018-08-13 15:07:46 EDT; 14s ago
     Docs: man:cupsd(8)
  Process: 3314 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cupsd -l (code=killed, signal=TERM)
 Main PID: 3314 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
Aug 13 15:07:46 john-max systemd[1]: cups.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 13 15:07:46 john-max systemd[1]: cups.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 13 15:07:46 john-max systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Aug 13 15:07:46 john-max systemd[1]: cups.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 15:07:46 john-max systemd[1]: cups.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 13 15:07:46 john-max systemd[1]: Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.

john@john-max:~$ sudo apt-get install cups
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cups is already the newest version (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

One thing which might matter: I recently opened Startup Applications and accidentally over-deleted some things there and don't know what they were.  Maybe something for the printer service was in there?

I also tried re-installing my printer drivers for my printer but it just says already installed.

On Ubutnu Software as well as by running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I show my software as all up to date.

I'm fairly novice so if you tell me what to do, if possible, please give me the actual terminal command.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cups`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yes I did that, and that ran, and when it was done I restarted my system.  But when it was all over my GUI Settings-Devices screen still says: 
"Sorry! The printing service doesn't seem to be available.", and if I run 'systemctl status cups' it still says 'Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.' in red at the end.

Comment: What's the next step, please?
The only thing unusual I was doing before all this problem started was I was trying to install some extended Ubuntu video codecs from the command line.  The printer was working on this OS before I did that.

Comment: I don't have time to learn all about CUPS just to fix this.  I'm thinking to reinstall Ubuntu which would take less time.

Comment: As you wish but do a backup of important data before reinstalling

Comment: Is there an easier way?

Comment: reinstall cups `sudo apt remove cups && apt install cups`

Answer (score 13):

I had same problem.  Config file is incorrectly located.
Follow directions as per this link.
    https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cups-service-stopped-um-18-04/17381

> There is a default configuration file which should be installed in
>   `/usr/share/cups/cupsd.conf.default` so I ran:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /usr/share/cups/cupsd.conf.default /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
> sudo service cups restart
> ```

Comment: Sorry that's too complicated for me

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. I believe that it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Same issue on a fresh install 18.4.3 ran both commands as suggested and it works for me. HP Officejet 6500 / Gnome

Comment: This worked for me also.  Thank you

Comment: I had the same problem in Debian! and this seemed to work for me too. Fanx!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by uninstalling Ubuntu 18.04 and reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04. Now not only the printer works, but the scanner too.
Good thing there's Long Term Support.

Comment: Hi there, are you still running 16.04 now that it's no longer officially supported? I have a similar problem on 20.04 on a newly-bought computer, and I'm not about to install an older version of Ubuntu on it.